# Ruby - IF and UNLESS statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I am a newbie Ruby user and I hesitate on the correct writing of this part:

```
<% if session[:user_id].nil? || (params[:controller] != 'home' && params[:action] != 'index') %>
    something
<% else %>  
    something else
<% end %>
```

But the first part of the IF construct is wrong (especially the **params** part). If I tried this:

```
<% if params[:controller] != 'home' && params[:action] != 'index' %>
```

So I got a bad results, but if this:

```
<% unless params[:controller] == 'home' && params[:action] == 'index' %>
```

So now I got already a good results...

Where could be a problem? What could be a wrong? The first code is what I need, but I don't know, how to join everything....

Comment: If you're asking a question about Ruby rather than Rails, you don't need the `<%` stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A != B AND C != D` is NOT the same thing as `!(A == B AND C == D)`

The first is true only when *BOTH* pairs are different. The second is true if *EITHER* pair is different.  In your example, to convert the unless to an if you would do:

```
<% if params[:controller] != 'home' || params[:action] != 'index' %>
```

So that the condition is true if EITHER don't match.

Read up on it here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective

Answer (score 2):

If this is working for you:

```
<% unless params[:controller] == 'home' && params[:action] == 'index' %>
```

The equivalent with `if` would be:

```
<% if !(params[:controller] == 'home' && params[:action] == 'index') %>
```

And passing that negation inside you get:

```
<% if params[:controller] != 'home' || params[:action] != 'index' %>
```

Notice how not only `==` becomes  `!=` but also **`&&`** becomes **`||`**